# MiniMagick cannot see an existing image file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minimagick

I am trying to open an image with MiniMagick and Rails, but no matter how I do it, MM does not see any images. I have spent several hours trying to figure this one out, but it's beyond me.

```
rails console

p = Provider.last
p.image_url
=> "/uploads/service_provider/image/35/Logo.jpg"

img = MiniMagick::Image.open(p.image_url.to_s)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/service_provider/image/35/Logo.jpg
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize'
```

or

```
i = MiniMagick::Image.open(p.image_url)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/service_provider/image/35/Logo.jpg
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize'
```

Appreciate any advice

Comment: Why didn't you used Rmagick , just curious .

Comment: Maybe it needs either the path or a fully qualified url?